# Solve deprecation about $this- get('twig')-> getextension('form')

Tags: symfony, twig, deprecated

I'm getting message like this in an application:

```
Referencing the "form" extension by its name (defined by getName()) is deprecated since 1.26 and will be removed in Twig 2.0. Use the Fully Qualified Extension Class Name instead
```

The code causing this is:

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('form');
```

There seem to be some related threads, but I've been unable to find a solution for this. I've also taken a deep look at deprecation notes, but I've been unable to find anything that, with my knowledge, helps me to solve the problem. I'd ask for a clear solution for what I have to do to get rid of this message, that doesn't allow me to even try to upgrade.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think I've found the solution. I just needed to find out the FQCN for the specific call, and it's

```
Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension
```

So, adding

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension;
```

and replacing

```
$this->get('twig')->getextension('form')
```

with

```
$this->get('twig')->getextension(FormExtension::class)
```

solved the problem.

I think there should be a more specific guide about what to replace and the replacement for each case.

Regards.

PD: I'm trying to find out how to mark this as solved, but maybe I'm not allowed to do this kind of things yet.

Comment: You have to wait 48 hours before you can self-accept an answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)